# Creating A New Admin Menu Tab For Theme Options

Tags: functions, wp-admin, admin-menu

I 've found an online tutorial that teaches how to implement a simple Options Page for the theme. I did it successfully but it is displaying as a sub menu, and I want it to be a main menu like those admin panel already have such as "Appearance,Plugins,Tools,Settings..." . How can I accomplish it? Here's my code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_global_custom_options');

function add_global_custom_options()
{
    add_options_page('Global Custom Options', 'Global Custom Options', 'manage_options', 'functions','global_custom_options');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the `add_options_page` line with the following:

```
add_menu_page( 'Global Custom Options', 'Global Custom Options', 'manage_options', 'functions','global_custom_options' );
```

Comment: Just one more thing, is there a way to exchange the before icon for one of my own?

Comment: I just figured it out, I can overwrite the :before for that tab